# Convert Long Long Int to int64_t in C by Assignment

Tags: c, integer, long-long

The following code converts a value of type `long long int` to a value of type `int64_t` by assigning a variable of type `long long int` to a variable of type `int64_t`. What are potential problems of this way of converting `long long int` to `int64_t`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (void) {

    long long int num = 9223372036854775807; // 2^63-1
    int64_t num64_t = num;
    
    printf("%lld\n", num64_t);

    return 0;
  
}
```

One problem could be that the  [ISO/IEC 9899:1999 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) specifies on p. 22, § 5.2.4.2.1, that the range of `long long int` is *at least* ±2^63-1, while the `int64_t` type has *exactly* 64 bits width. Could it be that on some machines values of type `long long int` are stored by using more than 64 bits? This could cause the above program to crash if the value of `num` would be bigger than 2^63-1 or smaller than -(2^63-1) because `num64_t` has only 64 bits available.
If this is a problem: Are there others? More generally: Is the above method a safe way to convert a value of type `long long int` to a value of type `int64_t`? If not, how could these problems be avoided?

Comment: You could compare the value to `INT64_MIN` and `INT64_MAX` before the assignment, to make sure the assignment will work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

> One problem could be that the ISO/IEC 9899:1999 standard specifies on p. 22, § 5.2.4.2.1, that the range of `long long int` is *at least* ±2^63-1, while the int64_t type has *exactly* 64 bits width.

C99 is obsolete, but the more recent versions of the standard (current is C2017) specify the same thing.  And yes, that is a potential problem: not so much the sizes of the types, but their ranges of representable values.  If you try to assign a `long long int` value to an `int64_t`, and that value is not representable as an `int64_t`, then either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

> Could it be that on some machines values of type long long int are stored by using more than 64 bits?

Yes, that is possible.  And also that the range of `long long int` is wider than the range of `int64_t`.

> This could cause the above program to crash if the value of `num` would be bigger than 2^63-1 or smaller than -(2^63-1) because `num64_t` has only 64 bits available.

Yes, if the result is to raise a signal then that could cause the program to crash.  It is more typical, however, that the conversion succeeds but (necessarily) produces a different value in the assignee.  That's arguably worse, as you are not immediately alerted to the problem.

> If this is a problem: Are there others? More generally: Is the above method a safe way to convert a value of type `long long int` to a value of type `int64_t`?

Assignment of an integer value to an object of any integer type automatically converts the value to the target type.  Conversions from one integer type to another are allowed and value-preserving when the value assigned is representable in the target type.  Although not relevant to your specific case, such conversions are allowed and well defined if the target type is unsigned, even if the original value is not representable in the unsigned target type. I have already described the effects in all other cases.

That is, no, there are no issues to be concerned about beyond the consequences already described of trying to assign an out-of-range value to the target signed integer object.

Comment: So one solution could be to check if INT64_MAX == LLONG_MAX or if INT64_MIN <= num <= INT64_MAX. Am I right that if one of the two conditions holds, the mentioned problems shouldn't occur?

Comment: Yes, @MoritzWolff, more or less.  Given `num` of type `long long int`, you can test whether `INT64_MIN <= num && num <= INT64_MAX` before assigning `num` to a variable of type `int64_t`.  That may involve (automatically) promoting `INT64_MIN` and `INT64_MAX` to type `long long int`.  In any case, it will allow you to ensure that only in-bounds values are assigned.  However, it still leaves you with the question of what to do if an attempt is made to perform an out-of-range assignment.

Comment: Where possible, it is better to choose types in such a way that the question does not arise in the first place.  So, for example, if you want `int64_t` then use it consistently throughout instead of mixing in `long long int`.

Comment: +1 for your remark on mixing types. The question arised in the context of an exercise involving taking a command line argument as input and converting the resulting string to the type int64_t. As I chose to use the function atoll() which takes a string and returns a long long int, I subsequently ran into these kinds of problems. I still don't know why the question was posed like that, but at least it made me think about the edge cases we discussed.